# Python - storing tuples returned by a function into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a piece of coursework, I have been asked to create some functions to input a lecturer's details and then store them in a tuple which I have done below.

```
def lect_input()
    payroll = input("Enter your Payroll. ")
    department = input("Enter your department. ")
    salary = input("Enter your Salary. ")
    forename = input("Enter your Forename. ")
    surname = input("Enter your Surname. ")

    list_lect = (payroll, department, salary, forename, surname)

def lect_details()
    str_lect = '{0:>15},{1:<25}{2:>15} {3:<10}£{4:<5}'.format(list_lect[3], 
    list_lect[4], list_lect[0], list_lect[1], list_lect[2])
    print(str_lect)
```

My next task reads as follows...

> In the main body of the program, write code which prompts the user for a filename and attempts to open the file whose name is supplied. If the file cannot be opened an error message should be output and the program should terminate; otherwise, the program should read each line from the file and supply it to the lecturer-creation function, storing the tuples returned by this function in a list.

so far I have managed to find a small snippet of code which can help me but I'm not sure where to go from this and am stuck trying 'read each line from the file'. As well as this I am not fully sure that what I have is entirely correct and would make my job easier later on in the exercise (I am still new to programming). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
f = raw_input("\n Hello, user. "
    "\n \n Please type in the path to your file and press 'Enter': ")
myfile = open(f, 'r')
```

^I have tried this but I'm not sure that's what I'm being asked to do.

Comment: posting the relevant-to-the question code would help us help you. Also, as a sidenote, keep in mind that your functions do not `return` anything so far.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis what do I need to do to complete the aforementioned functions?

Comment: "I'm not sure where to go from this and am stuck trying 'read each line from the file'." Just `with open(filename) as file:` then `for line in file:`.

Comment: @Shaun `return list_lect` for the first one so that the info you entered get passed to the main body of your code after the function exits

Comment: The "error message should be output and the program should terminate" will happen automatically, because that's what Python does when you try to `open` a file for reading and it doesn't exist.

Comment: From your edit, `raw_input` isn't going to work for you, because that's old Python 2.7 code you found somewhere. But you already _know_ how to input strings, because you're doing it in `lect_input`.

Comment: @abarnert I'm assuming I have to specify what the filename is then. In which case do I ask the user to input said filename and use that?

Comment: The assignment says "write code which prompts the user for a filename", so yes, you have to ask the user for the filename and use that.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis thanks will try that

Comment: @abarnert okay think I understand what I have to do now thanks. what would I use instead of `raw_input`?

Comment: @Shaun As I said, you already wrote code that does this, in your `lect_input` function. So just do the same thing you did there.

Comment: @abarnert ah alright sorry was skim reading the comments. thanks again